# client side javascript that always return the url to the nsf

Tags: javascript, path, xpages

I need a client side javascript function that always return the path up to the `.nsf` that can be used in XPages. e.g `http://acme.com/folder1/folder2/mydb.nsf/whatever/whatever`

it would be great if I could use the function like this

```
function getNSFPath(){

}
```

how do I construct a function like this?

Comment: and what is the usual place for "val.nsf" to be placed?

Comment: I understand you have a need, but what's your question?

Comment: the nsf is a filename like "home.nsf" and it is always in the root like this http://acme.com/home.nsf/whatever or in a folder http://acme.com/folder1/home.nsf/whatever

Comment: I kind of saw those downvotes coming, but I actually did google and wanted help to construct a really good function.

Comment: The down vote is for not taking the time and effort to write down a question we can answer. Even after your edit it's not clear to me what outcome of the function should be. It helps if you say things like "the current page is 'http://bla.com/dir/app.nsf/XPage.xsp' and I expect the function to return 'xyz'".

Comment: It is actually a valid question once you look at the border cases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XPages currently doesn't have a directory structure beyond the nsf. So it is sufficient to look for the last occurrence of / like this:

```
function getNSFPath(url) {
    return url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('/'));
}
```

In a future release that might change, so you want to look for ".nsf" instead. However that's not a save way either since a directory can contain ".nsf". Also a admin could decide to mask the NSF with an URL redirection, so you better consider an architecture where you don't depend on such a function

Comment: Code-only answers are discouraged and the site automatically flags them for review. Please write what the code does and how it addresses the specific question.

Comment: I think this works better
function getNSFPath(url) {
    return url.substring(0, url.lastIndexOf('.nsf'))+ ".nsf";
}

Comment: @Tom I agree, but given the simplicity of the question, the answer really is quite self explanatory. Explaining my answer would merely be repeating the question.

Comment: thank you Gwyn, you saw my problem and helped me in the right direction

Comment: This function will fail with a lot urls, f.e. *http://example.com/db.nsf/test.xsp?databaseName=test/test.nsf*.

Comment: If it's used to get url to the current application, you can use *document.location.pathname* to get the URL without parameters. Then you will avoid the problem Sven mentions. Combine this with substring to get the app path.

Comment: -1 Sorry, but this code will make so much trouble in apps... As mentioned above - it fails to retun correct URL in many situations, including XPiNC.

Comment: @stwissel: Why should XPages not have a directory structure beyond the nsf? The *databaseName* parameter is core XPages and can contain slashes...

Comment: Sven I meant: after the .nsf/xpagename.xsp is all we do for XPages currently. There is not .nsf/somedir/xpagename.xsp for now, but you could open an XPage via form property and you have more levels: .nsf/someview/docidorkey

Answer (score 1):

I would use something like this, to get the first occurrence of .nsf and also cover if someone has written .NSF I have seen that happend ;-)

function getNSFPath(url){
 return url.toLowerCase().split(".nsf")[0]+ ".nsf"; 
}

Comment: There is only a problem left: What if db is opened via replica id? ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a snippet that works with nsf and replica id path. Since *document.location.pathname* is used, you don't have to worry about parameters, as they aren't included.

```
function getCurrentAppPath(){
    // Extract path with replica id or nsf path
    return document.location.pathname.replace( /^(\/([0-9a-f]{16})|(.+\.nsf)).*/i, '$1/' );
}
```